# Setup Remote beanstalkd Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

My stack set-up consists of the following:

1. www.main.com - Main Server (Main Application code & supervisord)
2. www.queue-server.com - Beanstalkd installed here (No code here only beanstalkd)

I'm using **Laravel 4.2**.

I have setup **Supervisord** on **www.main.com** and added the following queue listener:

```
php artisan queue:work--queue=test --env=test
```

My `app/config/queue.php` file settings are as below:

```
'beanstalkd' => array(
    'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
    'host'   => 'www.queue-server.com',
    'queue'  => 'test',
    'ttr'    => 60,
),
```

From my understanding, it should push & process jobs on `www.queue-server.com` server but it shows no cpu spikes there, but `www.main.com` server shows high cpu usage.

So my questions are:

1. Is my setup correct? Or I have to change something?
2. I want to process my job on `www.queue-server.com` server. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beanstalkd server is just the storage of the queue data itself, it does no processing. Its the `php artisan queue:work` command that then processes the queue. This is why you are seeing the higher load on your `www.main.com` server as although your queue is stored on the other server, the main server is the one currently processing the queue.

If you wish for the `www.queue-server.com` server to process the queue you need to install your application there as well and run the artisan command from there.

Comment: Thanks Wader, ok I will make a copy of code on `www.queue-server.com` but user is going to use www.main.com only, thus `\Queue::push('myqueue',['data'])` code will executed on `www.main.com` only, will it work?

Comment: Yup thats fine. Install your code on your queue server and just run the `queue:work` command there, that'll process your queue on your queue server and leave your main server for the web.